# How to use multi select and setState in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, multi-select, flutter-change-notifier

I want to take multiple values from a dropdown field so i use multi select but i also use setState throughout the app. The thing is that values selected on seState get lost and thats a problem because i cant put more filters on my filtering in the list. I also tried Notifier but not much changed, actually nothing. it also needed setState.

I already tried Notifier so that i dont need to use setState but either i didnt use it properly or it doesnt fit my code , i cant find something else to use instead of multi select and cant seem to use multiselect without setState

Comment: Please share a code example of what you mean

Comment: As @MendelG said. Please share your codebase

Comment: @MendelG
DropDownTextField.multiSelection is my widget
When I use setState the value thats in the dropdown disappears and also if i open the dropdown there is nothing selected